# Postgresql concatenate tables

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I have map/reduce job which should create couple of tables during 'map' phase. The 'reduce' phase has to 'concatenate' those tables into single one, like

```
select * from A union all select * from B ...
```

What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Unless there's more going on than you've mentioned, you've already shown how.

Comment: I don't think that select with hundreds of unions is a good approach

Comment: @jdevelop Yes, `SELECT` from hundreds of tables is a bad idea. But creating hundreds of tables is even worse. Try changing the way you system works.

Comment: There's very little I can do for now, because 100 tables for 10K records will give 1M records in table, which is quite manageable for PosgreSQL. So if it could be possible to aggregate those tables - that would be just great.

Comment: "a couple" != "hundreds". So, yeah, more complete description please. Include your PostgreSQL version while you're at it.

Comment: postgresql version is 9.2.4, there could be 10-1000 of tables with 100-10000 records in each, I need to build single table from these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Map/reduce is a poor choice of things to do inside PostgreSQL with SQL and tables.  The reason is that everything runs serially and transactionally and this is probably not what you want.  In essence, you are trying to do something procedurally in a declarative language, in an environment not built to support it.

Your best option is to move the map/reduce phase out of your database and into your application, or to move to a system, like Postgres-XC, which will do the distributed queries for you in a transparent way.